# Testbed: Why is the default class injected and not my spy

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this setup code for my test

```
beforeEach(() => {
        loggerServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('LoggerService', ['log', 'naam']);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [UserslistComponent, BizPipe],
            providers: [
                { provide: UserdataService, useClass: MockUserdataService },
                { provide: LoggerService, useValue: loggerServiceSpy }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserslistComponent); 
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

What I want it to do is inject an instance of the `MockUserdataService` (which is does) and the created `loggerServiceSpy`.

Now in the `UserslistComponent`, the injected type of `LoggerService` is the 'real' `LoggerService` and not my spy.

I've seen this by console-logging the name of the LoggerService (I've given the loggerservice a `name` property).

This is the constructor for the `UserslistComponent`:
 `constructor(private userDataService: UserdataService, private logger: LoggerService) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the component if the services are provided in the component:

```
beforeEach(() => {
        loggerServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('LoggerService', ['log', 'naam']);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [UserslistComponent, BizPipe],

        }).overrideComponent(UserslistComponent, {
            set: {
                providers: [
                { provide: UserdataService, useClass: MockUserdataService },
                { provide: LoggerService, useValue: loggerServiceSpy }
            ],
            }
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserslistComponent); 
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

Comment: Whoot, this worked! I don't know how though. Most of the time when you know the answer, Googling for it is easy. But when I Google for it, I only get the Angular help (https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed) which basically says nothing and one other example for when you want to override the HTML in the template. Where could I have found such info?